# Tomcat7 server error, file not exist in directory or not a readable directory

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, tomcat7

When I run the spring project in eclipse using TOMCAT 7.0.42 I get the HTTP 404 error. In the console one of the error is

```
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\abcdLogin does not exist or is not a readable directory
```

when I was starting the server, the server start up get failed so I deleted the tmp0 tmp1 tmp2 folder from the above mentioned directory. I read somewhere that if the server doesn't start delete the folder from the directory. Now the server start ups but on console it is showing this error. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492454/eclipse-tomcat-error-document-base-does-not-exist-or-is-not-a-readable-director

Answer (score 2):

Try this steps, it may be help you

1. Clean tomcat work directory
2. Clean the server
3. Build project again on server

Comment: How to build the project again on server? Did you mean by re creating the whole project ?

Comment: No, from `project menu` in eclipse you will find build project, click on that and select your project and if you have select build automatically than there is no requirement of doing this just clean the project.

Comment: ok.. now I have cleaned the project as well build automatically but now error is:
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start

Comment: Increase start up time of server because spring takes more time to configure it self with server and withing that time if server get not start it will throw error, this may be reason for exact reason please give detail message which tomcat shows

Comment: the server has started now. but I am getting http404 error afte running the spring project. Also I am not able to see the logcat file of it as there is no option in eclipse to see. Eclipse version is: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Comment: Make sure your spring project has been configured properly, find for tutorial, up to now if this answer is useful to you, you can make it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple:

1. Delete the existing server
2. Create a new server
3. Delete the .snap file. Click to delete .snap file

Reference: [Tomcat7 server error, file not exist in directory or not a readable directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244233/server-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the problem:

1. go to Servers view (Window --> show View --> Other --> Server --> Servers)
2. Right click on TOMCAT 7 Server
3. Select `Clean ...` from context menu

Answer (score 0):

In case of Gradle,

I searched it everywhere for the gradle project but could not find solution till i keenly observed the gradle file. In gradle file the above line was missing,

apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove that server from Eclipse and create a new server in Eclipse. Then add your projects in to the new server, start the server from Eclipse.