# tomcat-maven-plugin throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am currently trying to add the tomcat-maven-plugin to my project, right now with the very basic configuration from their doc. In my pom.xml I have

```xml
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

and after a lot of research, I've come to add the following dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried changing the tomcat-version to the newest one, but that did not change anything other than messing up other parts of the code.

Now everytime I run `mvn tomcat7:run` I get the following errors:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1288)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:850)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:397)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jul 14, 2020 2:48:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
SCHWERWIEGEND: Parse error in context.xml for /cpc-fe
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/prj/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/target/cpc-fe/META-INF/context.xml; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 74; Error at (15, 74) : org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2711)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2743)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1291)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:850)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:397)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1288)
        ... 27 more

Jul 14, 2020 2:48:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
SCHWERWIEGEND: Occurred at line 15 column 74
Jul 14, 2020 2:48:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\prj\cpc-fe\cpc-fe-impl\target\tomcat\webapps\@docBase@ does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5141)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5326)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jul 14, 2020 2:48:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cpc-fe]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cpc-fe]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5327)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

Jul 14, 2020 2:48:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:342)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1242)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:595)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
```

Has anyone had the same problem before or knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that `tomcat-maven-plugin` is the correct version?

Comment: For the described execution I am just using maven from the command line, but the project was initially build with eclipse

Comment: The version for tomcat-maven-plugin is the one described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/dependency-info.html), and changing it to an older version like 2.2 only gives different errors

Comment: You may want to check this post (related to the "Document base ..." eror):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492454/eclipse-tomcat-error-document-base-does-not-exist-or-is-not-a-readable-director

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem: running the tomcat-plugin didn't work for me because my application was made for Tomcat 9 (that's where the ClassNotFoundExceptions came from). The tomcat7-maven-plugin with Tomcat 8 or above works only for deploy-like goals, not for tomcat7:run.

I ended up using the [cargo-maven2-plugin](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html) instead, which works with newer tomcat versions aswell, so my pom.xml now looks like this:

```
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
              <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.6</version>
              <configuration>
                <container>
                  <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                  <type>embedded</type>
                </container>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

You can start the server with

```
mvn cargo:run
```